# ORA-01722 invalid number error on a select query - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 SELECT 
    a.PCL_LOCATCODE, 
    a.AAG_NAME, 
    a.AAG_AGCODE, 
    a.CHL_LEVEL, 
    a.AAG_IDNO, 
    a.AAG_JOINDAT, 
    a.AAG_BRTHDAT, 
    a.aag_imedsupr, 
    a.aag_status, 
    b.AWT_TYPE, 
    b.AWT_EFFECTDATE, 
    c.GCA_REGNO, 
    c.GCA_REGEXPIRED 
FROM LAAG_AGENT a 
JOIN lawt_warnterm b ON a.aag_agcode = b.aag_agcode 
JOIN lgca_mainacnt c ON a.aag_agcode = c.Gca_Account 
WHERE 
    a.AAG_JOINDAT BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
    AND a.chl_level = '001';
```

When I submit this query I get an "Invalid number" ORA-01722 error.

Can anyone guide me please? I think the issue is in date condition.

Comment: From the documentation for Oracle error code [ORA-01722](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01722.php): ___Cause___ _You executed a SQL statement that tried to convert a string to a number, but it was unsuccessful_

Comment: does it work when you remove the where clause?

Comment: DDL for the tables?

Comment: Check the *data type* of the columns `a.aag_agcode, b.aag_agcode` and `c.Gca_Account`. Some of them are `NUMBER` some are `VARCHAR2`. All `NUMBER` columns wrap with `to_char` that will prevent the failed conversion to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of the data in the tables and there is type conversion occurring.  To track this down:

1. check all datatypes in columns that are being joined or subset in
   the where clause
2. if type conversion needs to occur, then make it
   explicit in your where clause so that you are not getting Oracle
   optimizer generated type conversion.
3. check the data by subsetting smaller numbers of rows 
   and/or checking each table/column where type conversion may be 
   occurring separately.